# UWP - FolderPicker Commit Button disabled inside initial folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an FolderPicker in my UWP app, implemented like this:

```
    var folderPicker = new FolderPicker
    {
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
    };
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder targetFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

When the folder picker opens, the explorer shows the content of the picture library, but the library/folder is itself not yet selected and the Commit Button is disabled and cannot be selected. The users has to navigate one level up to select the picture library folder and then he can click the button.

Is there a way around this? I want the user to be able to simply confirm that the picture library is the desired target destination and he just needs to approve this by pressing the commit button instead.

Answer (score 1):

Currently UWP's `FolderPicker` does not provide a setting to select the initial folder.

`SuggestedStartLocation` is to provide an initial starting location, but the newly created `FolderPicker` itself will not select the folder at startup. If there is no folder selected, the submit button will be disabled, which also causes the user to click the picture library folder for confirmation.

If you need to call the picture library folder, you don't need to use `FolderPicker`, but use `KnowFolders`:

```cs
var pictureFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
```

The premise is that you need to check `Pictures Library` in **Package.appxmanifest** > **Capability**.

Thanks.

Comment: I see, so this is probably a design flaw in the current implementation of FolderPicker/Windows, as I'm sure this has nothing to do with security, as the user still has to confirm with a button click. I cannot use your approach with "KnownFolders", as I want the user to be able to select a target folder. It doesn't have to be the picture library. This library is only the default one and should be directly selectable, which it currently isn't.

Comment: Yes, there is currently no setting item to change this behavior, `FolderPicker` does not select any folder by default when it starts.